# Keyboard switcher in Kubuntu, show language instead of country?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout, language-support

Kubuntu 19.10
I have two different keyboard layouts enabled, for the two languages I type in.
On the KDE panel, there is an icon for a keyboard switcher. I see options for it to show country flag, country name, or both. 
But I want neither -- I want the name of the language, instead. Is this possible?
For instance, English would be "En" or "Eng", instead of "us". Hebrew would be "He" or "Heb", instead of "il".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be configured when adding the keyboard layout.

1. Type "Keyboard" in the Kubuntu search bar, and select the first entry.
2. Switch to the "Layouts" tab
3. Put a tick in "Configure Layouts"
4. Click on "+ Add"
5. Choose a language
6. In the "Label" text box, clear the default label, and and your own. For instance, you can label English as "en"
7. Click on "Okay" at the bottom, and you're done. Now your language will be called as you chose.